# Operator norm of matrices of a change of basis

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices, functional-analysis, linear-transformations

Let $X = (x_1, \dots, x_d)$ and $Y = (y_1, \dots, y_d)$ be two basis of $\mathbb{C}^d$ such that $|x_n| = |y_n| = 1$ for all $n = 1, \dots, d$.
Then, there exists unique matrix of a change of basis $A(X,Y) = (a_{i,j})_{1\leq i,j \leq d} \in M_{d\times d}(\mathbb{C})$, that is, the following holds:
$$
(x_1, \dots, y_d) = (y_1, \dots, y_d) A(X,Y).
$$

Can we know something $\|A(X,Y)\|$, that is, the operator norm of $A(X,Y)$, or equivalently, $\|A(X,Y)\|_p:= (\sum_{i,j=1}^d |a_{i,j}|^p)^{1/p}$ ?

I hope $\|A(X,Y)\|$ is bounded with respect to $X, Y$, that is,
$$
C := \sup \{\| A(X,Y)\| : X \; \text{and} \; Y \text{are the basis of} \; \mathbb{C}^d\} < \infty.
$$
Furthermore, I really hope that $C$ is independent of $d$.

Comment: You need some additional normalization assumptions. Otherwise $C$ is infinite. For example $A$ can be diagonal with any nonzero numbers on the diagonal.

Comment: Can please confirm that the $\sup$ is taken over all bases $X,Y$? If so, $||A||$ is clearly not bounded. Take the basis $X=(1,1)$ and $Y=(\alpha,1)$ with $|\alpha|>1$. Since $\alpha$ is free, $C$ is not finite.

Comment: I'm really sorry, I edited. I forgot to write that normalization assumption. @RyszardSzwarc

Comment: By $|u|$ do you mean the euclidean norm ? Also the operator norm although is equivalent with the one you defined, but the equivalence constant depends on $d.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no, even for $d=2.$ Indeed, for $0<a<1$
let $$x_1=e_1,\ x_2=ae_1+(1-a^2)^{1/2}e_2,\quad y_1=e_1,\ y_2=e_2$$ where $e_1=(1,0)$ and $e_2=(0,1).$ Then for
$$A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & -a(1-a^2)^{-1/2}\\
0 & (1-a^2)^{-1/2}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
we get  $Ax_1=y_1, \ Ax_2=y_2.$ The operator norm of $A$ is greater than $(1-a^2)^{-1/2}.$

**Remark** The main reason that we cannot expect boundedness are the angles between the elements of the basis. The elements $y_1$ and $y_2$ are orthogonal, while $x_1$ and $x_2$ are nearly parallel, when $a\to 1^-.$